# Run output of existing VS Console project without a console window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I have a simple Console Project in Visual Studio that I want to run as a scheduled task but not show a console window when executing.  What's the best way to go about this?

In the initial use case, I need it to run as a Scheduled Task in Windows, but my uses for the application won't be limited to just running as a Windows Scheduled Task, hence I need a way to not show the console window within the project/executable itself.  Furthermore, I'm aware of how to start a console application from code and hide the output window.  I'd rather not have to have another executable start the existing app.

Comment: In case someone using Windows 7 or higher happens along and starts down this road be aware that on the 'Create Task' dialog there is a checkbox marked 'Hidden'. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to have a console application not show its output with an existing Console Project is to convert the project to a Windows Forms application and set the start up object to the existing `Program.Main()`.

(I did some googling before finding this resolution to my problem.  I'm posting the question/answer in case it will someone else.  Also, maybe there's a better way than this?)

Comment: [haw haw check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd)

Comment: That's how I do mine.... I just run it as a Windows Forms application and either hide the form or do my functionality in the Main()